# react-text comments causes invisible line

Tags: reactjs

*React Comments* like:

```
`<!-- react-text: 3 --> <!-- /react-text -->`
```

get rendered as empty line messing up with the design. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

**Edit: there is `something` between the opening and closing tags. It's not visible in the code above but in the fiddle. I copy pasted both from vim (see screenshot).**

https://jsfiddle.net/xokqyyxj/2/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React has added that block because an empty element was rendered. To remove it you will have to see where that empty element is generated. It is likely it is from an empty string - they can cause these seemingly unnecessary react comment blocks.

Comment: That put me in the right direction, thanks! After deleting a few "spaces" `git diff` shows me <U+2028> - WTH!!